# Discord.py - user.interaction problem with buttons

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**The Context:**
I'm creating a discord game where each channel represents a location in the game.

I have a button menu that moves a user from one channel to another when they click button 1. It does this by adding and removing roles attached to each channel.

The execution of button 1 has a delay in the form of asyncio.sleep(). This is to mimic travel time.

Button 2 appears in a response after a user clicks button 1. **The goal of Button 2 is to cancel the execution of button 1 while it's still executing.**

I am trying to achieve this by adding an if statement right before button 1 finishes executing. This if statement checks if the user has a role called 'cancel' which is added to the user when they click button 2.

If the user has the 'cancel' role, then button 1 just ends its execution immediately. Else it continues through with its normal execution.

**The Problem:**
User is defined as interaction.user. The user who interacted with the button.

The button function does not see roles added to the user after it has interacted with the button, only roles at the time of interaction.

Therefore, if the 'cancel' role is added after the initial button 1 click, the button 1 function can't see it when checking for it in the if statement.

Resulting in the check always saying the user does not have the 'cancel' role, even if they do.

Full code:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

# this just imports role names/ids from another file
import data.roles as ccroles


class cancel(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout = None)
    @discord.ui.button(label="Cancel",
                       custom_id="cancel",
                       style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def buttoncancel(self, interaction, button):
        user = interaction.user
        await interaction.response.send_message("You clicked me!",
                                                ephemeral=True,)
        await user.add_roles(user.guild.get_role(ccroles.cancel))
        print('Cancel added.')


class Menu(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout = None)
    @discord.ui.button(label="Location 2",
                       custom_id="location2",
                       style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
    async def button1(self, interaction, button):
        user = interaction.user
        if ccroles.location_1 in [y.id for y in user.roles]:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Traveling to Location 2!",
                                                     ephemeral=True, view=cancel())
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
            print('I waited 10 seconds.')
            if ccroles.cancel in [y.id for y in user.roles]:
                print('Cancelled travel.')
                await user.remove_roles(user.guild.get_role(ccroles.cancel))
            else:
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
                print('I waited 1 second.')
                await user.edit(roles=[])
                await user.add_roles(user.guild.get_role(ccroles.location_2))

class exampleMenu(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client: commands.Bot):
        self.client=client
        
    @commands.command()
    async def exampleMenu(self, ctx):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Travel Menu",
                          description="Where would you like to travel?")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed,
                       view=Menu())

async def setup(client:commands.Bot) -> None:
    await client.add_cog(exampleMenu(client))
```

**The Question:**
Is there any way to get the button 1 function, while it's executing, to recognize that the 'cancel' role has been added to the user?

Alternatively, is there any other way to achieve the goal of button 2?

*code is contained within a discord.py cog btw*
*thank you <3*

[example of how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktEFc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Like you mentioned, it will only see the roles the user has at the time of interaction. You don't necessarily have to have a role for everything, you can do the check within your code. In this example, I used a list.

```
travelling = []
class Menu(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout = None)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Location 2",
                   custom_id="location2",
                   style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
    async def button1(self, interaction, button):
        user = interaction.user
        if user.id not in travelling:
            travelling.append(user.id)
        #This works because .remove() removes all occurrences of this item
        #but you can also use try/except: pass
        await interaction.response.send_message("Travelling to Location 2!", 
        ephemeral=True, view=Cancel())
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        print('I waited 10 seconds.')
        if user.id in travelling:
            print("not cancelled") #do stuff here
            travelling.remove(user.id)
        else:
            print("cancelled") #do stuff here
        
class Cancel(discord.ui.View): #Should capitalise class name
    def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(timeout = None)
   
    @discord.ui.button(label="Cancel",
                   custom_id="cancel",
                   style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
   async def buttoncancel(self, interaction, button):
        user = interaction.user
        await interaction.response.send_message("You clicked me!",
                                      ephemeral=True, view=Menu())
        travelling.remove(user.id)
        print('Cancel added.')
```

However, if you would like to get the roles of the user, you can get the member object again after that 10 seconds which has the new set of roles:

```
class Menu(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout = None)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Location 2",
                   custom_id="location2",
                   style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
    async def button1(self, interaction, button):
        user = interaction.user
        await interaction.response.send_message("Travelling to Location 2!", ephemeral=True, view=Cancel())
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        print('I waited 10 seconds.')
        user = interaction.guild.get_member(user.id) #<<<
        #Your check v
        if ccroles.cancel in [y.id for y in user.roles]:
            print('Cancelled travel.')
            await user.remove_roles(user.guild.get_role(ccroles.cancel))
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            print('I waited 1 second.')
            await user.edit(roles=[])
            await user.add_roles(user.guild.get_role(ccroles.location_2))
```